# Required property per path and method

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, openapi

Consider the following sample specification:

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: stackoverflow question
  version: '1.0'
paths:
  /websites:
    post:
      parameters:
      - in: body
        name: website
        required: true
        schema:
          $ref: '#/definitions/website'
      responses:
        201:
          description: Website created
  /websites/{id}:
    patch:
      parameters:
      - name: 'id'
        in: 'path'
        type: 'integer'
        required: true
      - in: body
        name: fields
        required: true
        schema:
          $ref: '#/definitions/website'
      responses:
        200:
          description: Website updated
definitions:
  website:
    type: object
    required:
      - fieldB
    properties:
      fieldA:
        type: string
        readOnly: true
      fieldB:
        type: string
        format: date-time
      fieldC:
        type: string
        format: date-time
```

The `fieldB` property is required for both `POST` and `PATCH` methods. Is it possible to make it required only for a single path and method without having to specify two different model definitions?

If not, what would be a good solution to achieve this?